# generating parentheses using recursion and stack

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, stack

I am trying to solve this problem

*Given n pairs of parentheses, write a function to generate all combinations of well-formed parentheses.*

and I have done it the following way:

```
void gen_para(Stack* s, int n, int opened, int closed) { // recursive
    if (n == opened && n == closed) {
        print_s(s);
        // clear_s(s);
    }
    else if (opened < n) {
        push(s, '(');
        gen_para(s, n, opened + 1, closed);
        pop(s);
    }
    else if (closed < opened) {
        push(s, ')');
        gen_para(s, n, opened, closed + 1);
        pop(s);
    }
}
```

The function `gen_para` tries to recursively form well formed strings or set of characters and storing them in a stack one by one, when a string is found, it's printed (recursively) and then with recursive calls it gets poped, then we go to find another string. Note I use string here to mean the characters in the stack. I am using C, not C++.
This is my stack:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    char data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct Stack {
    char size;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
} Stack;

const Stack stack_init = { .size = 0, .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };

Node* create_node(char elm) {
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof * node);
    if (!node) return node;
    node->data = elm;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

Stack* create_stack() {
    Stack* s = malloc(sizeof * s);
    s->size = 0;
    s->head = NULL;
    s->tail = NULL;
    return s;
}

int is_empty_s(Stack *s) {
    return s->tail == NULL;
}

void push(Stack *s, char elm) {
    Node* updated_head = create_node(elm);
    if (!s->head) {
        s->head = updated_head;
        s->tail = s->head;
    } else {
        updated_head->next = s->head;
        s->head = updated_head;
    }
    s->size++;
}

char pop(Stack *s) {
    if (!is_empty_s(s)) {
        Node* node = s->head;
        char elm = node->data;
        s->head = s->head->next;
        if (!s->head)
            s->tail = NULL;
        s->size--;
        free(node);
        return elm;
    }
    return 'N';
    
}

char top(Stack *s) {
    char top;
    if (s->head)
        top = s->head->data;
    else
        top = 'N';
    return top;
}

void clear_s(Stack *s) {
    while (s->tail)
        pop(s);
}

Stack* reverse_it(Stack *s) {
    Stack *s2 = malloc(sizeof *s2);
    if (!s2) return s2;
    *s2 = stack_init;

    while (s->tail)
        push(s2, pop(s));
    s->head = s2->head;
    return s;
}

void print_s(Stack *s) { 
    if (!is_empty_s(s)) {
        char data = pop(s);
        // or place here instead printf("%c", data); if you want to print the other way
        print_s(s);
        printf("%c", data);
        push(s, data);
    }
}

int main() {
    Stack s1 = stack_init;
    int n = 2;
    gen_para(&s1, n, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

And I have a problem with printing the two expected outputs: `(())` and `()()`, only the first one is outputted and not the second one. I can't see why. Before the recursive call to go for the second well formed parenthesis, the stack is empty. What s going on?

Comment: What are you using the stack to represent?

Comment: Where are you creating multiple different strings? You're just pushing individual characters on the stack.

Comment: well formed parenthesis, I can understand that it is bizarre to have stack here, but it's just this problem is advertised a stack problem, I used stack.

Comment: @Barmar I am not creating different strings, it's C, and I print the stack after well formed set of characters is found.

Comment: Doesn't that answer your question about why you're only getting one result instead of all of them?

Comment: I am filling the stack for one set of well formed characters (string), stack is emptied, then it goes to be filled with the next set, no?

Comment: Your recursion is following a single path. At the end of it there is an output, and then it backs out of recursion without any new recursive call. What did you expect?

Comment: Why one path? This is strange, it should go over two. I plotted the paths here https://imgur.com/a/sXlODSH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written the function there is only one path going into recursion without any alternative that will be tried after that. Not that the chained `else` structure will prevent two blocks to both execute. So it is expected you only have one output.

You need to allow the last block **also** to execute when the middle block was executed (if the conditions are met).

So change to:

```
void gen_para(Stack* s, int n, int opened, int closed) { // recursive
    if (n == opened && n == closed) {
        print_s(s);
        printf("\n"); // For readable output
        return; // Exit 
    }
    if (opened < n) {
        push(s, '(');
        gen_para(s, n, opened + 1, closed);
        pop(s);
    }
    // Now also allow the next block...
    if (closed < opened) {
        push(s, ')');
        gen_para(s, n, opened, closed + 1);
        pop(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked the return and the ifs, when the fog gets into the brain, the brain need fresh air rather than stackoverfow, but thanks a lot

Comment: The absent return was not really a problem, but it needs to be added when removing the `else`. Yes, a walk in the park can be enlightening ;-)

Comment: Right, also the `clear_(s)` instead of `pop` after each recursive call is not possible because we remove some elements, this is the correct recursive tree https://imgur.com/a/Yr7u474, right? I mean if I used `clear_s` and not the two `pop`, I will remove that `(` from which the recursive tree stretched

Comment: Yes, the idea of `pop(s)` is to restore the stack back to the state it had before the `push` that happened just before the recursive call. The `pop` is the "undo" action for that `push`.